# Clojure - reset! atom causing a stack overflow

Tags: clojure, stack, overflow, reset

I am learning clojure and just playing with atoms and refs.  Here is a simple tree implementation, but it is causing a stack overflow when executing the add-child method:

```
(ns mytree)

(defprotocol PNode
  (add-child [this parent] "add 'this' node to the parent"))

(defrecord Node [id parent name children]
  PNode
  (add-child [this p]
     (println "adding this to children of parent")       
     (dosync
      (alter (:children p) conj this))

     ;following causes a stack overflow -why?
;        (println "reseting parent of this")
;        (reset! parent p)

     ))

(defn create-node [id name]
  (Node. id (atom nil) name (ref ())))
```

Here is a sample session from REPL:

```
>mytree> (def root (create-node 1 "CEO"))
>#'mytree/root
>mytree> (def child (create-node 2 "VP1"))
>#'mytree/child
>mytree> (add-child child root)

>adding this to children of parent

>(#:mytree.Node{:id 2, :parent #<Atom@4dffa9d: nil>, :name "VP1", :children #<Ref@cbe5beb:      ()>})

>mytree> root
>#:mytree.Node{:id 1, :parent #<Atom@44896098: nil>, :name "CEO", :children #<Ref@2a75733a: >(#:mytree.Node{:id 2, :parent #<Atom@4dffa9d: nil>, :name "VP1", :children #<Ref@cbe5beb: ()>})>}
>mytree> (def child2 (create-node 3 "VP2"))
>#'mytree/child2

resetting parent to child2 works
>mytree> (reset! (:parent child) child2)
>#:mytree.Node{:id 3, :parent #<Atom@43c32b82: nil>, :name "VP2", :children #<Ref@425d868f: ()>}

but resetting parent to root causes stack overflow - why??
>mytree> (reset! (:parent child) root)
>; Evaluation aborted.
```

As you can see above, reseting parent of child to child2 works, but resetting it to root causes a stack overflow.  Can you help me understand why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not actually the `reset!` but the REPL trying to print the (infinitely) nested values.

Try this:

```
(set! *print-level* 10)
```

That will limit the recursive printing of hierarchical objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can you explain where does the recursion come from when doing this?  I was just trying to set the parent "pointer" of the child node to the parent.  Don't understand why that results in an infinite recursion.

Comment: Because if `root`'s parent is `child`, and `child`'s parent is `root`, you've got a [cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CycleGraph.html). The return value of `reset!` returns the new value, which the REPL tries to print, which will go on forever without a `*print-level*` value.

Comment: OK - I think I understand what is going on.  REPL is trying to traverse all the links to print the structure, and since child was added to the root earlier, now when child's parent is set to root and when REPL tries to print the root, it will print the children and follow their links which leads back to the root, so infinite recursion when trying to print.

Comment: Thanks John - yeah, I just realized it and posted but looks like you posted the answer even earlier.